# Python tkinter - Unable to position child frame while using nested frames

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I was experimenting with tkinter,

#Created black frame

```
frame=Frame(root, width=366, height=559,bg="black")
frame.pack(padx=(0,0),pady=(0,0))
```

#Placed grey frame and magenta frame ON black frame

```
frame2=Frame(frame, width=349, height=57,bg="grey").place(x=8, y=10)
frame3=Frame(frame, width=70, height=473,bg="magenta").place(x=8, y=74)
```

#Placing Blue frame ON magenta frame, at (0,0), but this goes to the root's (0,0)

```
frame4=Frame(frame3, width=50, height=50,bg="blue").place(x=0, y=0)
```

The grey and magenta frames are perfectly placed relative to the the black frame
But the blue frame goes to the root window's (0,0). Why? How will i place blue frame on the magenta frame?

[image]

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Fee Fie Foe Fum")
frame=Frame(root, width=366, height=559,bg="black")
frame.pack(padx=(0,0),pady=(0,0))
frame2=Frame(frame, width=349, height=57,bg="grey").place(x=8, y=10)
frame3=Frame(frame, width=70, height=473,bg="magenta").place(x=8, y=74)
frame4=Frame(frame3, width=50, height=50,bg="blue").place(x=0, y=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All of your `frameX` variables are `None`, the result of calling `.place()` rather than an actual Frame.  Passing `None` as the parent to a widget constructor makes it a child of the root window, so you don't actually have the widget structure that you think you have.  You need to do the geometry management as a separate statement from the creation of the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue frame `frame4` goes into the root window because it uses `frame3` as a parent. `frame3` is `None`, which tkinter treats the same as if you had passed the root window.

The reason `frame3` is `None` is because `place` (and `pack` and `grid`) all return `None`. Threfore, `Frame(...).place(...)` returns `None`.

IMHO, it's always best to separate widget creation from widget layout. It results in the need for some temporary variables, but using a single style (always separating the two) makes the code easier to manage than sometimes using one style and sometimes using the other.